# FileChooserDialog stuck on screen after destroy()

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a python script, requesting a file from user using FileChooserDialog. When done, it calls .destroy() on the dialog, but immediately after that begins to load the file. Since it is usually a large file, dialog "stays imprinted on screen" until parsing is done, main window created and MainLoop run. Is it possible to "refresh X" or sth, or do I really have to create some "loading window"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to force GTK to refresh the screen

```
        while gtk.events_pending(): #   this forces the refresh of the screen
            gtk.main_iteration()
```

before opening the file